# Kibana dashboard couldn't connect with Nginx

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, reverse-proxy, kibana, kibana-4

Hi i'm trying to use Nginx as a reverse proxy for accessing a Kibana 4 dashboard. The location of the dashboard is not available in the latest kibana but it can be accessed using a URL.

Kibana and Nginx are running both locally and installed on a windows machine installed in C:\

Kibana is running on localhost:5601. 
I installed NGinx and configured it to run on port 80. My config file of Nginx looks like this.

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  127.0.0.1:5601;


        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }


        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

       location ~ {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5601;
            #proxy_redirect https://kibana/;
        }
}
```

But when i enter localhost in my browser i see,

"Welcome to nginx!

If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx."

Kibana is working fine with : localhost:5601. 
Do i need to make any changes to the Kibana config file also? I want to access the kibana dashboard by localhost:80 through NGinx.

Thanks

Comment: Look at the 2 location blocks, both point to the same 'area' but the first matching will handle requests, so either move proxypass to one location or use a named location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change "server_name  127.0.0.1:5601;" to "server_name  localhost:80;"

Add this upstream above "server {" :

```
upstream kibana {
    server localhost:5601;
}
```

and then replace "location ~" with :

```
location /kibana/ {
    proxy_pass http://kibana/;
}
```

Use http://localhost/kibana to access Kibana

Comment: Thank you, i got it working but i am able to use kibana by entering localhost AND localhost:5601. So i shouldn't be able to access it by typing localhost:5601. How to do that?

Comment: Rudra's comment below is correct - You can't limit access to port 5601 on localhost as it's needed by kibana - BUT - He's iptables rule will block the port for any ip except localhost - You will not be able to access kibana using url _server ip_:5601, thus effective blocking the port

Answer (score 0):

I have configured my nginx to reverse proxy the kibana-4 dashboard. The following nginx config does the job for me:

```
    server {
    listen 80;

    #You can add your fqdn, say example.com, if you want to in the next parameter
    server_name localhost;

    auth_basic off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, are you able to restrict access to the dashboard using localhost:5601? I just want to access the dashboard using "localhost"  but my dashboard is loading if i enter localhost:5601 directly in the browser.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to restrict access to the dashboard where data is visualized for lots of users. Each user can see only his report based on his current login information. So i don't want anyone to access the dashboard just by giving the Kibana URL . Therefore i want a solution where a dynamic URL is generated in the back so  when someone clicks the report button in his account he can see his dashboard only. His username will be passed as a parameter to the Kibana server.

Comment: It looks more of a network configuration question. We cannot restrict localhost from accessing 5601 since nginx needs it to show a dashboard anyway. You can restrict any external IPs to access that port via the following command:



`iptables -A INPUT ! -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5601 -j DROP`

Source: [This](http://serverfault.com/questions/248851/iptables-block-port-8080-but-not-for-localhost) SO question

Comment: You might want to replace `127.0.0.1` with `localhost` if you're trying out the command in previous comment.

Comment: Thank you so much. But is there a way for Nginx to convert a request for the kibana dashboard into a dynamic URL and then proxy it to the kibana server.The URL is in the format http://localhost:5601/#/dashboard/Dashboard-1?_g=(refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause:!f,section:0,value:0),time:(from:now-30d,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(filters:!((meta:(disabled:!f,index:'*',key:name,negate:!f,value:torres),query:(match:(name:(query:torres,type:phrase))))). Now if someone copies the above URL and changes the name value from torres to xyz, he can see data about xyz. So i need a dynamic url generated.

Comment: I don't have in deep knowledge of nginx configuration syntax and but I came across [this Server Fault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/160790/nginx-rewrite-for-an-url-with-parameters/161029#161029) that is trying to achieve something similar. Using this to create the url and using it alongside the conditional statements, should do the trick (A slightly educated guess). Hopefully this might help you to find the way.

Comment: Here are a few other resources:

1. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables
2. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into it

Comment: Kindly upvote if anything has beeb of any relevant help. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can proxy to kibana through nginx kibana and ES on a remote server with https using letencrypt

```
        server {
        listen [some_port] ssl http2;
        server_name [server_name];
        root /your/root/directoty;

        location /app {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/yyyyyyyyy.passwd;
        proxy_pass http://example.com:5601;
       }


       location /bundles {
       proxy_pass  http://example.com:5601/bundles;
       }
       location /elasticsearch {
       proxy_pass [http://elasticsearch_server:9200;]
       }
       location /status {
       proxy_pass  http://example.com:5601/status;
       }
       location /api {
       proxy_pass  http://example.com:5601/api;
       }

       location /plugins {
       proxy_pass  http://example.com:5601/plugins;
       }


       location /ui {
       proxy_pass  http://example.com:5601/ui;
       }

       location /es_admin {
       proxy_pass  http://example.com:5601/es_admin;
       }

       location /built_assets {
         proxy_pass http://example.com:5601/built_assets;
       }

       location /node_modules {
         proxy_pass http://example.com:5601/node_modules;
       }

       location /translations {
         proxy_pass http://example.com:5601/translations;

       }

      location /internal {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:5601/internal;
      }   

     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem;
     ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/chain.pem;
     include snippets/ssl.conf;
     include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

     access_log /var/log/nginx/xxxx.access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/xxxxx.error.log;


     passenger_enabled on;
     passenger_min_instances 1;
     client_max_body_size 10m;

}
```